# Find the middle element of a string array

Tags: java, arrays, search

I would like to know how to do a dichotomous search in a String array?

```
public static int rechercheDicho(String cherche , String [] t) {
        int debut = 0;
        int fin = t.length-1;
        boolean trouve = false;
        
        for(int i =0;i<t.length;i++) {
         int resul = cherche.compareTo(t[i]);
        
        int milieu = (debut + fin)/2;
        while(debut <= fin && ! trouve ) {
            if(t[milieu] == resul) {
                trouve = true;
            }else if(resul > cherche) {
                fin = milieu-1;
            }else {
                debut = milieu +1;
                
            }
            milieu = (debut+fin)/2;
            
            } if(trouve) {
                return milieu;
            }else {
            return -1;
            }
        }
        }
```

I have already made this code but it doesn't work because for t[middle] there is a conflict between String and int

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you are comparing a String to an int like so:

```
if(t[milieu] == resul)
```

Array `t` is a String array, which means all the items within the array are of type String. The `==` is undefined for the type comparison of String and int.

Specifically, here:

```
public static int rechercheDicho(String cherche , String [] t) {
    int debut = 0;
    int fin = t.length-1;
    boolean trouve = false;
    
    for(int i =0;i<t.length;i++) {
     int resul = cherche.compareTo(t[i]);
    
    int milieu = (debut + fin)/2;
    while(debut <= fin && ! trouve ) {
        >>>if(t[milieu] == resul) {<<<
            trouve = true;
        }else if(resul > Integer.parseInt(cherche)) {
            fin = milieu-1;
        }else {
            debut = milieu +1;
            
        }
        milieu = (debut+fin)/2;
        
        } if(trouve) {
            return milieu;
        }else {
        return -1;
        }
    }
    }
```

I believe you should be parsing it to an int, then comparing like so:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(t[milieu]) == resul)
```

Alternatively, you could try converting it to a String, then using `.equals()`, although this is much more tedious and slower

```
if(t[miliu].equals(String.valueOf(resul)))
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but you can't compare with the "<" or ">" operator.

Comment: @WanWan Sorry about that. Just parse it to an int. I've edited my answer